# Creating a node/express API that spawns an async Python subprocess

Tags: python, node.js, express, asynchronous, subprocess

Technically, it spawns a Python subprocess that spawns another async Python subprocess, but the title was already long. Node/ExpressJS should wait on the first Python subprocess (to ensure it ran successfully), but not the sub-subprocess, which can take several minutes to complete. However, despite seemingly having the right setup, the API request when made through the browser seems to hang up waiting for the subprocess of the subprocess.

**Background:**

The basic goal here is to create a Node/ExpressJS based API you can use to run a model then get the output. The model can take several minutes to run so my strategy, instead of just waiting for the response with one API request, is to split the request into two, one to prep/run the model, a second to retrieve the results.

The prep call initiates the model, there's checks and etc. by userid to make sure only one model run is active per user at any time. It simply returns a message saying the model run has been started successfully or that you can't start a new run because it's currently running.

The retrieve call tries to retrieve the data. It can return a message saying the output is still running, the error if the run failed, or the stats and numbers and whatnot if the model run has completed.

**Problem:**

The problem is in the prep call. Node/Express calls a prep.py script. The prep.py script spawns another subprocess (run.py) but neither Node/Express or prep.py should wait for that subprocess to complete. Otherwise, calling the REST API would hang up if waiting for the model to complete.

So the way this is done in Python is as follows:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen([
    "python",
    os.path.join(this_dir, "run.py"),
    userid,
    processid
])

print json.dumps({'response': 'success'})
# end of script
```

When running this via command line (i.e. CMD), this works fine. I call prep.py, it instantly dumps the JSON and CMD is ready for another input/command. On the task-manager I can see python is running in the background and eventually the model output file will appear where I need it to.

However when calling it via Node/ExpressJS through the browser, the API still acts like it's waiting on run.py to complete. (Eventually it timesout, the browser auto-refreshes, and the page says something to the effect of "error, model is already running" -- which at least is nice to see the failsafe work to prevent spamming model runs.)

Here's the path through which the API prep call is made:

```
router.route('/prep/:userid/:key')
    .get(throttle(tOptions), function(req, res, next) {
        var error = null;
        RunPy(
            // path to script
            path.join(process.env.PYSCRIPTDIR, "prep.py"),  
            // parameters/arguments
            [req.params.userid, req.params.key], 
            // on complete callback
            function(ret) {
                if(error) {
                    next({message: error});
                } else {
                    res.send(ret);
                }
            },
            // on error callback
            function(err) { error = getPythonError(err); }
        );
    });
```

RunPy just being a convenient wrapper to run python subprocesses:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

module.exports = function(pyPath, args, onComplete, onError, onData) {
    var py = spawn('python', [pyPath].concat(args));
    var ret = "";
    py.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        ret += data.toString();
        if(onData) onData(data.toString());
    });
    py.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        onError(data.toString());
    });
    py.stdout.on('end', function() {
        onComplete(ret);
    })
};
```

I could probably just ensure the python scripts only output once and just have the on complete callback fire on the first `py.stdout.on('data', ..)` but that seems inelegant and I don't like the idea of just leaving a hanging Javascript thread waiting on this python script that takes several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the one work around I figured is a bit wonky (I feel like) but it works. Maybe a better answer will pop up though.

Basically I create a preprep.py (better name needed), this does the stuff that requires Node/Express to wait (e.g. check if model is already currently running for the user). It doesn't start the model, it just returns 'true' if it's all clear to run or raises an exception if it's not. Then Node/Express runs prep.py and doesn't wait or care for a response, just assumes it started up successfully and moves on.

```
router.route('/prep/:userid/:key')
    .get(throttle(tOptions), function(req, res, next) {
        var error = null;
        var onError = function(err) { error = getPythonError(err); }
        // on complete callback with a nested RunPy call
        var onComplete = function(ret) {
            if(error) {
                // error handling same as before
                next({message: error});
            } else if(ret.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').toLowerCase() === "true") {
                 // if response (stripped of whitespace and lowercase) is true send success response
                 res.send({response: "success"});
                 // run prep.py with no callbacks
                 RunPy(path.join(process.env.PYSCRIPTDIR, "prep.py"), [req.params.userid]);
            } else {
                // just for completeness
                res.send({response: "could not start model"});
            }
        };
        RunPy(
            path.join(process.env.PYSCRIPTDIR, "preprep.py"),
            [req.params.userid, req.params.key],
            onComplete,
            onError
        );
    });
```

Also RunPy slightly modified so now all callbacks are optional obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind your setup seems fine, I think you're just getting confused with a small detail.

You correctly point out that you have to split the response into two parts, 'minute-long process initiated' and 'data now available'. But in your actual code you have conflated the two into one, and your Express server doesn't return anything before the Python script is done.

What's hanging is not the server but the client, who doesn't receive anything for minutes and consequently times out after a while.

So ideally, your server should return something immediately that tells the client to go into 'waiting mode'. Then you can think about how the client will figure out when results are available.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding how subprocess.Popen operates, but I thought it spawns an async process for which the script that called it doesn't have to wait on. At least running it on CMD, it prints {"response": "success"} (what Express should return) and resets the terminal for a new command instantly. [Oh I had a typo, I added the "print" command to the original post]